# What's wrong when use mypy to check type

Tags: annotations, python-3.5, type-hinting, mypy

```
from typing import Dict, List, Any, AnyStr, TypeVar
def abc(xyz: str) -> Dict[AnyStr, Any]:
    return {"abc": 1}
```

And I use mypy to check this file. It's giving an Error.

Below is the Error message

> "Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "str": "int"; expected "bytes":
>   "Any""

But I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `AnyStr` is actually an alias for a typevar. This means your program is actually exactly equivalent to writing:

```
from typing import Dict, Any, AnyStr, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', str, bytes)

def abc(xyz: str) -> Dict[T, Any]:
    return {"abc": 1}
```

This, however, presents us with a problem: how is mypy supposed to infer which of the two possible alternatives you wanted for T?

There are three possible fixes. You can either...

1. Find some way of using `AnyStr` at least two or more times within your type signature. For example, perhaps you decide this is really more what you meant?

   ```
   def abc(xyz: AnyStr) -> Dict[AnyStr, Any]:
       # etc
   ```
2. Use `Union[str, bytes]` instead of `AnyStr`:

   ```
   from typing import Union, Dict, Any

   def abc(xyz: str) -> Dict[Union[str, bytes], Any]:
       # etc
   ```

   If the type signature is starting to get uncomfortably long, you can shorten it by using a type alias:

   ```
   from typing import Union, Dict, Any

   # Note: this isn't a great type alias name, but whatever
   UnionStr = Union[str, bytes]

   def abc(xyz: str) -> Dict[UnionStr, Any]:
       # etc
   ```